# What code quality / code coverage tools are available for checking Javascript tests in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, jasmine

What code quality / code coverage tools are available for Jasmine?

Working in Rails 3.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use a combination of [JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/CodeCoverage) and [this Jasmine adapter](https://github.com/ibolmo/jasmine-jstd-adapter) to get coverage metrics.

[JSCoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/) is a C based tool that you run out of band from the command line..

[JesCov](https://github.com/jescov/jescov) is a Java solution that supports Jasmine. You can run it from the command line, so it should be fairly straight forward to integrate with Rails if the system has a JRE:

`java -jar jescov-0.0.1.jar one.js two.js three.js`

I looked into JesCov several months ago for a Grails project, but never actually tried it out, so I'd be interested in hearing your experience if you  do try it.

Comment: Sounds complicated. Is there a step-by-step process?